# How can I change the position of the colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i try change position  of jquery colorbox i have both tried in css and  java and nothing works. also tried the  other thread but  none of the suggestions  have  solved it for me.

Comment: Looks like you tried some things, could you post what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following.

```
$.colorbox({
    href: 'mypage.html',
    top: '100px',
    left: '40%'
});
```

There're many other options that you can see [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

Answer (score 0):

I normally do these for left positioning of my colorbox

```
 jQuery.colorbox({html:response.html,scrolling:false, overlayClose:false, maxWidth:"480px", maxHeight:"345px", left:true});
```

Try something like this, instead of left:true you can mention  percentage by what you want it to position it